# Calculating the covariance matrix of an object's points - Rotation of an object

Tags: objects, coordinates

I am trying to calculate the axes of largest variances of an object's points. As you might know, the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of the points should yield the result.

For a cube (which is made out of 8 evenly spread points) I would therefore expect to get the three axes of the cube. However, this is only the case when I did not rotate the cube, but when I do, my method yields axes that are not correct.

Here is some code I use to calculate the axes:

```
import bpy
import numpy
from numpy import linalg as LA
vertices = bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices
matrix_world = bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world
verticesArray = numpy.zeros((3,len(vertices)))
counter = 0
for v in vertices:
     world_coord = matrix_world * v.co
     verticesArray[0,counter]= world_coord[0]
     verticesArray[1,counter] = world_coord[1]
     verticesArray[2,counter] = world_coord[2]
     counter = counter + 1
convMat = numpy.cov(verticesArray)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = LA.eig(convMat)       # the eigenvectors determine the axes I want
```

As you see, I firstly transform all vertices to world coordinates. I guess somewhere there has to be an error that does not account for the rotation or something...
Do you have an idea what I am missing?

Comment: the object vertices are probably stored in the local coordinate system of the mesh, so you'll either need to create or specify a transformation matrix to retreive the world coordinates them.  i don't have a lot of python experience, but I did run into this issue in AutoCAD quite often

Comment: @JohnBurrill: I believed that is what I am doing by multiplying the coordinates with "matrix_world", but there seems to be sth wrong with that. Maybe someone knows what and which matrix I need to use...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the addon **Math vis** to display vectors, in addition to testing your code in the console.

Paste the following in the console to see that the vertices are placed at the right locations. I don't know enough maths, but maybe the problem is in the numpy operations...

```
import bpy
import numpy

#from mathutils import Vector

from numpy import linalg as LA
vertices = bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices
matrix_world = bpy.context.active_object.matrix_world
verticesArray = numpy.zeros((3,len(vertices)))
counter = 0
for index, v in enumerate(vertices):
    globals()["vertex"+str(index)] = matrix_world * v.co ##vector to global variable
    world_coord = matrix_world * v.co
    verticesArray[0,counter]= world_coord[0]
    verticesArray[1,counter] = world_coord[1]
    verticesArray[2,counter] = world_coord[2]
    counter = counter + 1

convMat = numpy.cov(verticesArray)
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = LA.eig(convMat)
for index, vec in enumerate(eigenvectors):
    print(index, vec)
    globals()["vector"+str(index)] = Vector((vec[0], vec[1], vec[2]))

del world_coord
del matrix_world
print(eigenvectors)
```